# after execve, are memory in the previous process addr freed？

Tags: linux, execve

In execve function, arguments are passed by a pointer array. If these pointers ponit to memory in the previous stack, can these memory still be accessed in a new process image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[20] = "a.out";
    char str[20] = "hello\n";
    char *argv[3];

    argv[0] = filename;
    argv[1] = str;
    argv[2] = NULL;
    execve("/hel/a.out", argv, NULL);
    return 0;
}

/*   /hel/a.out code   */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);  /** Here, should the memory pointed by argv[1]
                               *  be freed after execve  has been called?
                               */ 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should use `strace`

Comment: Yeah.I put your trace code in main, and the output is a bit complicated. I'm learning Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment and want to finish it to gain a global concept. After that, maybe It's time for studying every detail.

Comment: Perhaps I get it.  If  a=13; (high byte 00, low byte 0d)                                  argv[1] = (char *)(&a);     In the second main,correctly output  format like: printf("%s", argv[1]);      // print '\n'                                                                   Copy only the argument and environment strings to new locations in execve. I don't  know whether I'm right or not. Thanks for all the answers and I'll study it deeply afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read *carefully* the documentation of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (and also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) to get a broader view). Read about [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s, [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).

The **`execve` [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is installing a fresh new [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)** in your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (so the old virtual address space of the program doing `execve`  successfully disappears, being overwritten by the new one), so you don't share any data with the previous one (and a successful `execve` does not return, since the new program is started). Your new program would be able to later change the virtual address space, e.g. with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...

<sup>The address of `argv` strings in the new virtual address space are independent of the address of arguments to `execve`; the string contents are the same. No *data* is *shared* between the old virtual address space and the new one, but arguments to the new program (and program environment) are *copied*. Read also about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)</sup>

The arguments of `execve` are *strings* copied (with their copy being pushed) on the new fresh call stack of the new virtual address space for its starting function (`_start`  in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) which calls `main`). Of course you should not `free` any `argv[`i`]` - that would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

<sup>Hence `int a; argv[1]=(char*)&a;` ... `execve` with `argv`,  is undefined behavior, because you cannot guarantee that the memory zone at the address of `a` is a proper null-terminated string. Read about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) & [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).</sup>

So `execve`  wants a `NULL` terminated array `argv` of proper *strings* (not arbitrary pointers), and another `NULL`  terminated `env` array of strings, and each string should be terminated by a zero byte. There is a rather small limit `ARG_MAX` (typically 128Kbytes) on the total memory space copied from the old address space to the new one thru `argv` & `env`.

You might *perhaps* use shared memory (see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)) to share memory between various processes (and you'll synchronize with semaphores, see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)...); but you often would prefer other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) techniques (e.g. [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s, etc...).

BTW, use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand which system calls are involved by your program, and use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), notably by running `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/`*`$pidofyourprogram`*`/maps` to understand more about virtual address space.

You could even put in both of your `main` functions (before `execve` in the first one, before `return 0;` the second one) something like

```
 char cmd[64];
 snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "/bin/cat /proc/%d/maps", (int)getpid());
 printf("before running %s\n", cmd);
 fflush(NULL);
 int err = system(cmd);
 if (err) fprintf(stderr, "system failed err=%d\n", err);
 else printf("system %s done\n", cmd);
```

This will show you a view of the virtual address space. Of course, a more serious program should `fopen` a `/proc/1234/maps` file and loop on `fgets` to read every line until `EOF` then `fclose`.

Be patient, read all the references here, and take [time](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) to learn more about POSIX programming. Studying some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) source code (e.g. on http://github.com/ you can chose some interesting projects...) and contributing to them should be worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah,thanks. I find the a.out output correctly. Would global variable be kept and local be freed? I have read execve(2) again and don't find anything about this.

Comment: Variables are inside the virtual address space. And since the entire VAS is replaced, your question has no sense. You really need to spend several hours reading the links I gave in my answer.

Comment: Different VAS after execve. independent address but same contents about strings. I test such code ' int a = 3;          argv[1] = (char *)&a;'    and in a.out  source file : ' printf("%d\n", *((int *)argv[1]));'  The output is a random number.

Comment: @hl: yes, because `execve` is *copying* the *string* of each `argv`, and `(char*)&a` is *not* a *proper* string (null-terminated, and generally UTF8 encoded, even if `execve` don't care about encoding)

Comment: a=3 and stored (00-03). If so, can execve correctly copy (00-03) in the new VAS? Since the two bytes are null-terminated.But it's a random number.

Comment: Please, take several hours to read all the links (since you have a confusing picture in your head)... Try the `cat /proc/$$/maps` experiment. I cannot teach you everything in a few paragraphs. You'll need days to learn all this. Be patient, and start to work by yourself.

Comment: I still can't understand a = 3. whether it can be treated as null-terminated string regarding to 00-03?     int a=3; argv[1]=(char*)&a; Sorry to bother you. And I'll learn more about execve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98466/discussion-between-hel-and-basile-starynkevitch).